# Microsoft Excel 2013 on Windows 7, creating cost based on drop down values

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Hi I am need of some assistance and was wondering if anyone can help me. I am creating a spreadsheet for quoting jobs on site and am stuck with a particular part.

I have a cell containing a drop down list of 5 different types of product, of which each one represents a different cost. I need a formula that will calculate the total cost, based on which type of product is chosen, and how many of these will be purchased.

For example;

Product A = £5.00
Product B = £10.00
Product C = £15.00
Product D = £20.00
Product E = £25.00

If someone wishes to purchase 7 of Product B, I need the formula to see that I have selected Product B from my drop down list, and that it needs to then times the value of this product (£10.00) by the number of these they wish to purchase (7). The number of products selected is input into a separate cell.

Can anyone assist?

Can provide screenshots of requested.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown control requires you to to specify a cell link. When you select something from the dropdown list, the linked cell will be updated with the index of the item you selected, as shown below.

[image: Excel Format Control dialog box]

You can now use the `INDEX` function to pull the corresponding value.

[image: Excel index function]

**Tip:** I usually position the dropdown list so that it obscures the linked cell.